# Having an image fill a container after transform(90deg)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

I would like to have an image rotate and fill the container after it's been loaded. The issue I'm having is the height is automatically set when loaded and then not resetting after rotation. Here is a JSFiddle of the issue:

```js
$('.load').on("click", function () {
 var image = $('.image');
  
  image.attr("src", "https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/f5/a0/62/f5a0626a80fe6026c0ac65cdc2d8ede2.jpg");
  
  image.addClass('rotate-image');
  
 });
```

```css
.image {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%; 
}

.rotate-image {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="img-container" style="background:black; height:100px; width: 200px; text-align:center">
  <img class="image" src="" />
</div>

<br />
<button class="load">Load</button>
```

Comment: Do you want it to fill the container by width and height or only by height?

Comment: I would like the image to maintain aspect ratio, filling which ever is more appropriate, so in the example it would be height, after rotation.

Comment: Add `width: 100px;` into `rotate-image` class.

Comment: I need the solution to be responsive and work with various images

Comment: I don't think this could be done without some sort of gimmick. `transform` just visually rotates the element, while the flow of the website remains the same. It would be pretty hard to match the now rotated dimensions of the image with whatever it is contained in since the website recognizes the image as not rotated. The fact that you _see_ it as rotated changes nothing.

Comment: If it's only visual could you think of any other way to rotate the image in a way that actually orientates it? I would have though this to be a fairly simple thing. I've tried adding the max-width/max-height after transforming it to no avail

Comment: If you use my solution, check the edit I made because it's pretty important.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This requires the `max-width` and `max-height` styles to be removed, though.

To fit the image, it has to be made larger so that it *width* (height, when rotated) becomes as big as the container's height. However, it's rotated only visually and the browser doesn't care about that because `transform` doesn't change the flow of the website. For it, there is an "unrotated" picture whose height is now bigger than its container. Visually rotating the image doesn't change anything. For that purpose, the image needs to be pulled up with a number of pixels equal to how much its bigger than the parent. Those pixels are divided by two because the image overflows at the bottom only.

Play with the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e2gs62ty/) to see what I mean.

```js
$('.load').on("click", function() {
  var image = $('.image');
  image.attr("src", "https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/f5/a0/62/f5a0626a80fe6026c0ac65cdc2d8ede2.jpg");
  image.addClass('rotate-image');

  var parentHeight = image.parent().height();
  image.css("width", parentHeight + "px");
  image.css("position", "relative");
  image.css("bottom", ((image.height() - parentHeight) / 2) + "px");
});
```

```css
.rotate-image {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="img-container" style="background:black; height:100px; width: 200px; text-align:center">
  <img class="image" src="" />
</div>

<br />
<button class="load">Load</button>
```

**Edit:** Beware, if you load the image from an external source by setting its `src` and immediately rotate it, `image.height()` might return 0 and the image might be displaced. Then, if you click again, its height is now correct and it gets placed right.

I'm not absolutely sure, but I think that's because when you load the image, the browser needs to download it first, meaning that you don't yet know what its dimensions are.

To see that in action, paste some image URLs from Google in the fiddle I provided.

Comment: Overflow:hidden on the container makes this the ideal solution, thanks very much. I will implement it and mark it as the answer

Comment: Thanks for that additional edit, I actually have a solution in place for that already, using a function that gets the remote URL's width/height and then the rotation code is in a callback

Answer (score 0):

You need to do this by javascript or jquery. Your goal is:

> .Rotated_Img ...
>
> width = 100 % of parent height
>
> height = 100 % of parent width

And i do not think css has any think for this, until the parent width and height have related to view port **vw and vh**.

jquery:

```
$('.Rotated_Img').each(function(){
  $(this).css('width', $(this).parent().height() + 'px');
  $(this).css('height', $(this).parent().width() + 'px');
});
```

Comment: This would lose the aspect ratio of the image, I assume?

Comment: Of course. If you want same ratio you need only set width or height and another one is auto. `$(this).css('height', 'auto');

Comment: Setting it to `auto` will not work, because the browser doesn't know what it's actual width or height is. If that would work, what will happen if the image is rotated 45 degrees? The website has its flow and `auto` is set according to that. CSS `transform` **doesn't** change the flow.

Comment: You said *browser doesn't know what it's actual width or height* what you mean? width or height of image? The browser knows the ratio between width and height of an image. and to rotate 45 deg you need to calculate the diagonal of the image and set `(height ^ 2) + (width ^ 2) = parent height` or some calculations like this. It is not (what you want) a popular thing and have not known solution, and you need to make hard effort to do.

Comment: The browser doesn't know that when you rotate the image 90 degrees its width is now its height and its height is now its width. That's why I think `auto` wouldn't work.

Comment: To test rotate an image without changing width or height. If the parent has not enough space the image will shrink, but the ratio will not change after rotation.